# Set value of hyperlink with WPF by code

Tags: wpf, hyperlink

I'm using WPF and an Hyperlink control with

```
    <TextBlock Margin="98,190,116,133.418" FontSize="14">
        <Hyperlink Name="hyperlink" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            Click here
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

this is working, but I would like to set the "click here" value by code, but I'm unable to find the correct property.

```
hyperlink.Value ?
hyperlink.Text ?
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content: [Hyperlink Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.inlines.aspx)

Url: [Hyperlink.NavigateUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.navigateuri.aspx)

[Hyperlink Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink_properties.aspx)

Comment: I use this : hyperlink.NavigateUri = new Uri(value); but nothing visible, text is empty

Comment: yes, If i let the "click here" in the xaml, I can click on it and go to the good url with          
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));

            e.Handled = true;
        }

Comment: for example, I use : hyperlink.NavigateUri = new Uri("http:// www.google.co.in", UriKind.Absolute); (whithout the space before www, else the formating is bad)

Comment: So the problem is the display text? You should examine the `Inlines` property which contains the actual text of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 15):

An alternative answer, which I consider more straightforward than working with the inlines is to put a `TextBlock` (with `x:Name`) inside the `Hyperlink` and then call its `Text` property in the code behind:

```
<TextBlock Margin="98,190,116,133.418" FontSize="14">
    <Hyperlink Name="hyperlink" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        <TextBlock x:Name="hyperlinkText"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Then in code behind you can set the hyperlink's text by calling `hyperlinkText.Text`, like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.hyperlinkText.Text = "some custom text";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be the accepted answer, since just throwing three links here from your clipboard is clearly not!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `Inlines` property this way:

```
hyperlink.Inlines.Clear();
hyperlink.Inlines.Add("Your text here");
```